# Drawing the Drawable of icon of an app doesn't works

Tags: java, android, canvas, view, drawable

I'm creating a launcher app on Android, and I get the icon of an app by calling `mResolveInfo.activityInfo.loadIcon(mPackageManager)`. The problem is that when I'm trying to draw this drawable on canvas in `draw` method of my custom view by calling `icon.draw(canvas)` (where "icon" is the drawable), this draws nothing.

BUT if I set the drawable as the background of the view, it draws the icon pirfectly when I call `super.draw(canvas)` method.

I don't know what the `View` class does with the drawables to make them work, but it proves that there must be a way to do this, and I absolutely need to avoid using of `super.draw(canvas)` method, because I need to customise what my view is drawing when it's focused (if I use my app with a keyboard, for example).

**Edit: *if my question helped you, please vote it, I have not enough reputation because of stupid questions I have posted in the past so I'm not able to ask a new question no more***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey, finally I found a solution by myself, before somebody was able to answer my question.

The problem is that the bounds of the drawable were null(all zero), so I just had to call `icon.setBounds(0,0, width,height)`(where "icon" is the drawable) and now it draws correctly.

And this is one of things that the `setBackground(drawable)` method of my view doing with any drawable that I give it.
Hope it helps somebody who had the same problem.